# Using node7 with typescript and angular-cli how to?

Tags: node.js, angular, angular-cli, typescript2.0

Can anyone demonstrate on how I can bundle them together and play nicely? I would like to use all the new cool features of node7 and typescript2.0.

And one more question how do I use it in enterprise project?

Answer (score 0):

Just install nodejs 7 globally. Then use Angular CLI which is already using TypeScript 2.x.